# How to fix hover CSS on animated ribbon

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a animated ribbon but I have had luck making it.

When I use hover on left-id it works but when I try to use on RibbonContainer or right-id it doesn't work.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
#RibbonText {
  background: #5bdfb8;
  color: #009;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: width .5s, padding-right .5s, visibility .5s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#RibbonContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
  left: -6px;
  transition: width 2s, box-shadow 2s;
}

#left {
  height: 33px;
}

#RibbonContainer:hover+#RibbonText {
  width: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="RibbonContainer">
  <img id="left" class="RibbonImage" alt="ribbon-shwadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
  <span id="RibbonText" class="ribbon">
            {ribbonText}
          </span>
  <img id="right" class="RibbonImage" alt="ribbon-end" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is changing this `#RibbonContainer:hover + #RibbonText` to `#RibbonContainer:hover > #RibbonText`

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation. You might also copy the snippet down here and make changes to demonstrate your solution.